# How to create local Live Agent instance in microsoft health bot service

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I have created a health bot using microsoft health bot service and created some scenarios. I am able to embed the bot in external application. Now, I need the bot to connect to the live agent. I referred [Microsoft handoff overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/handoff#deploying-the-agent-webchat) documentation but with no luck. Can anyone tell how to create agent scenario and call a Live Agent in Health Bot Service?

Comment: If you provide some insight about your tries and also about the failing point that would be better for everyone. In the current shape the question is too broad to answer.

Comment: The issue is I could not find a starting point on how to create a **Handoff to live agent** from my health bot.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @RohitMungi-MSFT's answer, you likely need to have an "agent" logged in before the user attempts to enter the handoff queue.

Here are [the handoff docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/HealthBot/handoff).

Steps:

1. Deploy [the sample website](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/tree/live_agent_handoff)
2. Add your HealthBot's APP_SECRET and WEBCHAT_SECRET (found in Health Bot > Integration > Secrets) to the Azure resource of the website you deployed in the previous step (under Application Settings).
3. Have the "Agent" Log In (with any name/ID for the sample) at `https://<yourSite>.azurewebsites.net/agent.html`
4. Have your user/patient enter the webchat at `https://<yourSite>.azurewebsites.net/`

After Step 3, the agent should see:

[image]

After Step 4, the user/patient should see:

[image]

The agent will then see:

[image]

For implementing your own local Agent site, you can see that [the sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/blob/live_agent_handoff/public/agent.js#L20) just sends:

```
chatRequested({
    userId: user_id.value,
    userName: user_name.value,
    agent: true // <--- the important part
});
```

#### Note

Currently (3/4/2019), you may get an error when the handoff is initiated due to an issue with sending variables to the Handoff Scenario. If you go to Scenarios > , then double-click the last step (the one with Scenario trigger: /builtin/handoff)”, delete everything in the Arguments box; you shouldn’t get that error any more.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It was so helpful. But still I could get "User xxxx has joined the waiting queue". After that I enter message from agent and I am not able to see the message in the bot. It does not show any response from the agent.

Comment: I can't get it to work, either. It appears that Health Bot went back into preview, so I'd imagine this is a bug. I know handoff is a newer feature, as well, so it may just take some time to iron out the kinks. Health Bot will be great because it's so easy to build a complex bot; it's unfortunate it's still in Preview. It's still possible to build a very complex bot more manually. You can [see this sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) for human handoff that requires much more coding to set up.

Comment: ...Correction: it didn't go "back into preview", it just went from "private preview" to "public preview", recently.

Comment: So, Is that the reason why it doesn't work? Could you explain the terms "private and public preview" and can you tell when will it go back to working mode?

Comment: That feature doesn't work because it's new and especially when in preview, is likely to have bugs. Every team is going to define their "previews" differently, but think of "private preview" as "early alpha and likely to have several bugs, so let's only let MS employees use it", "public preview" as "beta, likely has some bugs, but those who are interested are welcome to use it", and "released" as "we've gotten rid of just about all of the bugs and it's ready for anybody to use". I don't know when it will be "released." I can say that human handoff will be VERY important for this bot...

Comment: ...so it will eventually get fixed.

Comment: @mdrichardson - MSFT Thank you for updating the answer with the argument issue. Any idea when it will be fixed? It's been a few months..

Comment: @miraco I don't. Unfortunately, HealthBot is being worked on by a very different team than the rest of Bot Framework.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can let us know where exactly you are having issues in the handoff scenario.

Is handoff activated your bot? Handoff functionality is disabled by default. To use this feature activate handoff from your management portal.

Navigate to Configuration > Conversation > Human handoff and enable handoff.

Then select "Handoff to Human" from Scenarios -> Template Catalog and then follow the rest of the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthbot/handoff#implementation-examples).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I have enabled the handoff functionality. But when I select and use "Handoff to Human" from Scenarios, it says "Currently agents are unavailable". Can you tell me the procedure to create local instance of Agent bot. I have local instance of my health bot already.

Comment: You can use the Free Tier and deploy the [sample website](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/tree/live_agent_handoff) for the agent using the app service.